# Sortable BindingList for custom column

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, bindinglist

I have a DataGridView which is data-bound to a BindingList. My DataGridView also has a couple of custom columns that I have added. These are not data-bound, but rather are generated based on items in my BindingList 
(ie: an item in my BindingList of type A has a property of type B; my custom column shows B.Name 
In this case, "Name" is a property of class B, and thus the property represented by the column is not directly found in the items in the BindingList).

**Can anyone help me for this?**
I wanted to make it **generic**.

e.g.

```
public class Fruits
{
  public String Id {get;set}
  public String Name {get;set}
}

public class People
{
  public String ID {get;set}
  public String Name {get;set}
  public Fruits FavouriteFruit{get;set}
}
```

In BindingList as we can do sorting using custom sortable list for the properties on People, in the DatagridView but, I also wanted to sort  People based on the FavouriteFruit.

Comment: I'm not sure, but I would guess that you need to add the column (and data) to the base DataSource..

Answer (score 1):

You can inherit DataGRidView and add the required properties.